# Writing swift protocol for exiting objective-c class

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I'm trying to write a protocol to do UnitTest by making a double for GIDSignIn in GoogleSignIn framework.
GIDSignIn is written in Objective-C and I'd like to extract delegate and presentingViewController from GIDSignIn

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<GIDSignInDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
```

However, when I wrote the protocol below, I got warnings saying about different optionality. I would like to know how I can write my protocol silencing these warnings.

[image]

Comment: [`weak var delegate: GIDSignInDelegate! { get set }`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn#/c:objc(cs)GIDSignIn(py)delegate) & [`weak var presentingViewController: UIViewController! { get set }`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn#/c:objc(cs)GIDSignIn(py)presentingViewController).

Comment: write your protocol in objc instead and see why it's throwing those warnings. 
And your delegate id can point to null at any time.
Overwriting protocols is not a perfect design pattern, consider using the original which is the idea of having protocols otherwise you tend to violate the intended protocol.